# Scala spray immediately close connection after send answer

Tags: scala, tcp, spray, so-linger

How scala spray immediately close connection after send answe?

In other http server I`m set tcp options`so_linger` = 0

Where I can set so_linger param in spray_can?

Comment: `so_linger = 0` is the default. It isn't part of your solution, on any platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `Connection("close")` header on the response. Spray-can will then close the connection.